# Parallel compilation giving problem in MSYS2

Tags: windows, msys2

When I am compiling with J8, sometime I am getting the following error:

C:\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe -C firmware all -j8 -O
Compiling file: project/src/tests.c with optimization level:  -Os

error: unable to open output file 'build/tests.o': 'no such file or directory'
1 error generated.

This happens randomly.
If I change J8 to J1, then compilation is always successful. There is no problem with path or directory permission as compilation is working with J1 and sometime with J8.

My setup details:

1. MSYS2
2. ARM Compiler v6.16
3. Windows 10

Not sure whether it is a problem of MSYS2 or ARM Compiler or Window specific problem.

Comment: Show your makefile. Maybe you have several targets writing to the same file, or missing dependencies between targets.

Comment: That error makes it sound like the `build` directory doesn't exist.  How is that directory created?  Are you deleting it or creating it at all in any of your Makefile rules?